# VB.Net Access Query Stop Rounding Decimal to Integer

Tags: vb.net, csv, ms-access, oledbcommand

i am using  OleDbCommand for importing CSV when i am using query its rounding the decimal to integer. 
For Example My Table Data is Below

```
 SalID  Commission 
    1        2.5
    1        2.5
```

My Access query is `select salID, Comission from table GROUP BY SalID, Commission`

Output should be

`1 ..... 2.5`   but instead its showing output

```
1.......2
```

its rounding 2.5 to 2. but when i use simple query without group . it works perfectly its show 2.5 
thank you

Comment: As is, a _group by_ cannot cause this. Thus, something else you don't tell about is going on.

Comment: Yes Your Right . I tested my code many times. and found out. if first row value is in Decimal(2.5) . It works Correct if First Row Value is in Integer(5). it round up the other value in datagridview When Importing From CSV

Comment: Makes sense. But I don't know how to add and use an _import specification_ with OleDbCommand. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add a Cdbl() over the commission field (in group and select clause).

This would help the database engine to determine the type of this field.

Comment: select salID, CDBL(Comission) from table GROUP BY SalID,  CDBL(Commission) But its still not working still showing 2.0 insted of 2.5

Comment: Okay, as you have said in your comments. It's all about the "guessing type column" engine of jet engine. There are several trick about that. One of the "safest" is forcing the interpretation of all column as string by adding "IMEX=1" in the extended properties of the connection string. But don't forget to cast or convert the column in your futher calculation...

Answer (score 0):

I think if ADO.net is unsure of the type, it samples the first few pieces of data to determine the data type for a particular column.
Try explicitly adding the columns to your DataTable before you fill it.

```
Dim columns As DataColumnCollection = DataSet1.Tables("Orders").Columns
columns.Add("Total", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"))
```